# Context menu styling in HERE maps

Tags: angular, here-api

I'm using [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/events/context-menu) example to create a context menu in my map but the font is too small.

```
event.items.push(
  new H.util.ContextItem({
    label: 'Label',
    callback: function () { }
  }),
  H.util.ContextItem.SEPARATOR,
);
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting:

[image: here is a screenshot of what I'm getting]

Is there a way to change the font size and the style in general (background color etc) of the context items?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at how it works in the example? Live HTML examples are great, because as web developers we can inspect the element and use the example as an example of how we might customise the output.

You can see below that the font size is coming from `.H_context_menu`.

I don't know if this class is added as standard or they have added it for the demo. My point is that you can do the same on your own version - inspect the HTML to find out what CSS classes you get for free, or what font sizes you need to override.

You may even need to somehow add your own CSS class via the library.

However you end up achieving this, try to see what's already going on via the dev tools in your browser. You can then either experiment by overriding the existing styles in the dev tools or adding styles to your project and reloading the page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't expecting this to be so simple!